# Make Binding/IValueConverter lower priority

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter

I am displaying list of files and everything relies on Bindings and IValueConverters. The problem is that icons generate slowly as also some data like MP3's ID3 tags which I extract with IValueConverter supplying it with a path to song.

Since I use Virtualization experience is horrible: on scroll files update one by one, and I would prefer ID3 tags to populate after all other IValueConverter have finished updating.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `Binding.IsAsync`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Use the IsAsync property when the get accessor of your binding source property might take a long time. One example is an image property with a get accessor that downloads from the Web. Setting IsAsync to true avoids blocking the UI while the download occurs.
>
> While waiting for the value to arrive, the binding reports the FallbackValue, if one is available, or the default value of the binding target property.

Comment: I already have IsAsync=true on all bindings but it stills refreshes files one by one.